# OnCollisionEnter not called when two colliders collide

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, collision-detection

In my 2D game, there is a ball with a circle collider ,and a platform with a box collider.

The ball has a material for bounciness and a rigidbody2D. The platform only has the box collider.

I find it to be as simple as could be, but it's not working for some reason, so apparently it's not that simple. Here's the C# code snippet found in the ball class which is attached to the ball game object:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    Debug.Log("Hit");
    animator.Play("Bounce");
}
```

Why isn't the function being called on collision? Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Set the `isTrigger` property to True in the collider you want to trigger this event

Comment: there's a problem with that, the ball then goes through the gameobject, I want it to bounce off the platform, not go through it.

Comment: Can you confirm that when you say "box collider", you mean "box collider 2D"? Don't be confused by the comment made by @LuisMasuelli; you only want your collider to be set as a trigger *if it actually acts as a trigger*. Setting it to `isTrigger = true` will not likely fix your problem, but rather *cause more problems*.

Comment: yes, everything is the 2d ones.

Box Collider 2D,
Rigidbody 2D,
Circle Collider 2D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use collision events for 2D. You are using the events for 3D collision detection where your colliders and rigidbody components are for 3D.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    Debug.Log("Hit");
    animator.Play("Bounce");
}
```

Comment: perfect, damn, I think I did almost that but with a lowercase d or something which caused it to not work. Sorry abou that :P but thank you!